# Symfony3 ClassNotFoundException after bundle creation

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I wanted to start a new 3.3 project in Symfony and started as usual:

1.) Creating the new project: `symfony new ArtProject`

2.) Creating a new Bundle: `php app/console generate:bundle` (Paul/ArtBundle, yml, src/)

Then I run the local server and when I open 127.0.0.1:8000 I get this beautiful message:

> **(1/1) ClassNotFoundException**
>
> Attempted to load class "PaulArtBundle" from namespace
>   "Paul\ArtBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another
>   namespace? in AppKernel.php (line 19)

Which is strange and I haven't figured out why this happen so far. Before creating the Bundle, there was no error; I saw the typical startpage of symfony.

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        ......
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new Paul\ArtBundle\PaulArtBundle(),
    ];
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Paul\ArtBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class PaulArtBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Any idea whats going on there? I did not change a thing, I only ran these commands.

Comment: Check AppKernel.php ,   is it correct ?

Comment: @SamJanssens yes, I also can jump to the php file in my IDE fromt he kernel

Comment: Did you well registred the new Bundle @ Appkernel.php file ?

Comment: well there is clearly a namespace issue going on somewhere,   but where ...

Comment: @SamJanssens I added the excerpt from the AppKernel

Comment: and just to make sure,   the use statement is also on the top ?

Comment: @SamJanssens Yes

Comment: weird ...   try completely removing the cache (actually deleting the folder), then try the cache clear command, then let composer rebuild your bootstrap file,   if none of that helps,    restart your project i guess ;) ...   i havent run into this particular issue before ..

Comment: @SamJanssens Actually, I also did this.. twice :D

Comment: Seem to be getting a rash of these questions.  Check the autoload section of your composer.json file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928982/appkernel-php-weird-behavior#comment76834486_44928982 Might be something screwy with the latest release.

Comment: @Cerad Sadly, this didn't work either

Comment: I'm wondering why is this happening with a LTS version of Symfony. Why @favpot?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I just installed a fresh copy of S3.3.4 (latest version as of this writing) using:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition s334 "3.3.4"
bin/console generate:bundle
Share across multiple apps: yes
namespace: Paul\ArtBundle
bundle name: PaulArtBundle
Target Directory: src/
```

Refreshed the browser and sure enough I got the class not found message.

The generate:bundle command is not updating the autload section of composer.json when a new namespace is introduced.  Edit composer.json and:

```
# composer.json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "Paul\\": "src/Paul"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

Then run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And restart the server(maybe).  That should fix the bundle class not found problem.

I have not used the generate:bundle command is quite some time ever since the standard was to put everything under AppBundle so I don't know how long this has been "broken".  But at least three questions in the last week or so indicates it was something recent.

And by the way, when I refreshed the browser I got "Hello World" which threw me for a bit.  Turns out the new bundle overrides the / route which is also sort of special.

And in case anybody is wondering why this started happening, Symfony 3.2 changed from

```
#composer.json
"psr-4": { "": "src/" },
To
"psr-4": { "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle" },
```

You could always just change it back though I think spelling out individual namespaces might be "better".  Not sure.

And here is an issue with more details: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/1098

Looks like the maintainer favored a tiny speed improvement over breaking an existing command.  Oh well.  Symfony Flex is supposed to make everything great again.

Comment: Yup, worked, after is restarted the server. Tahnks :)

Comment: awesome work there. Thanks for the answer. Spent days literally fighting this.

Comment: I just posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151067/class-not-found-exception-in-appkernel-after-moving-to-symfony2-8-24 which you marked as duplicate and yes, this one is quite similar only I was going from 2.8.9 to 2.8.24 (in which the **psr-4** entry is already different) and did what was instructed here except the `composer dumpautoload` line which is off the table for me as I mentioned in my question, can you indicate a workaround for this, thanx

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!

Comment: Is this really changed in Symfony3 that a new Bundle must have to be in the composer.json added?

Comment: @MiracleJohnson - You can just change the psr4 line back to { "": "src/" }, if you want.  Slight performance hit but not enough to notice.

Answer (score 3):

If you generate a bundle for **usage in multiple projects** (with own namespace) you need to add it in the `composer.json` as follwed:

Lets assume your bundle name is `CompanyFooBundle` with namespace `Company\Bundle\FooBundle` then the composer autoload section should look like:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Company\\Bundle\\FooBundle\\": "src/Company/Bundle/FooBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the "Company\\Bundle\\FooBundle\\", my mistake was : "CompanyBundleFooBundle\\"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in:

Generate your Bundle with

> ./console generate:bundle

And follow the steps as always, now, do what you want in your composer.json file with the line

```
"AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
```

Replace  with `"": "src/"` or add your bundle, for example: `"BackendBundle\\": "src/BackendBundle"`

**Here's the new part**:

1. Install composer in your bin directory, copy and paste the steps from https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Up a level in your project directory, and in your root folder (of your project) run the next command

php ./bin/composer.phar update

Answer (score 0):

Removing `vendor` dir and again running `composer install` helped me with same problem.