# Symfony 3.3 Getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony

I have updated my system to from Symfony 3.2.x to Symfony 3.3.x and now I cam getting this error for every bundle in my application:

Attempted to load class "XXXXXXXXPublicBundle" from namespace "XXXXXXXX\PublicBundle".

Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

In my PublicBundle I am using the namespace:

```
namespace XXXXXXXX\PublicBundle;
```

When I try and run php composer.phar update I get this error too:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "XXXXXXXXPublicBundle" from namespace "XXXXXXXX\PublicBundle".
```

What is going on - I have no clue what to do. Any assistance?

Comment: try removing vendor directory contents and then run composer install

Comment: Probably related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820

Comment: Do you have more information on the class that triggers this error in the debug? Have you updated the `app_dev.php` and `app.php` files to have a line that looks like `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` instead of `require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';` ?