# Rename Symfony AppBundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, rename

I try to rename an Symfony Bundle.
My Installation is 3.4 and Standart.

Installed symfony-installer and Generate AppBundle.

Now i has modified the AppBundle, and all works Nice!

Next Step to try is rename AppBundle to TestBundle.

I have changed `src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php` into `src/TestBundle/TestBundle.php`
Then opened it an Change the Namespace to TestBundle and the classname also.

In AppKernel chage:

```
new AppBundle/AppBundle()
```

To:

```
new TestBundle/TestBundle()
```

The TestBundle will Not be called. I have insertet an

```
die("called!!!")
```

Into TestBundle. So i doesnt have to change anymore, i should see "called!!!".

But i See:

> Attempted to load class "TestBundle" from namespace "TestBundle". Did
>   you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

What have i to do??

Thanks!!!

Comment: clear cache and check if you have correct namespaces

Comment: Remove cache results in this error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TestBundle\TestBundle' not found in /var/www/vhosts/*.com/httpdocs/*/app/AppKernel.php on line 18. manually cleared but Same error. Namespace in TestBundle.php is correct

Comment: You need to adjust composer.json.  This is basically a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820

Comment: I have found an Solution. I changed the autoloader class-files and it works! Later i will try your Solution, But i think its exaktly the Solution. Your Link will use the composer file and updates the autoloader file! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Check you're namespace in file `-> AppBundle.php`, change to TestBundle, and rename you file to `TestBundle.php`. 
Then chack settings in `config/routing.yml`

```
defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:ControllerName:ActionName }
```