# Symfony 3 bundle creation always throws "Edit the composer.json file"

Tags: php, json, symfony

Hi I've been learning symfony, and every time I use the "php bin/console generate:bundle" command to create a bundle, even though I leave everything by default, I keep getting this error:

> The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
>    You'll need to make the following changes manually.
>    Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
>    namespace in the "autoload" section:

I saw here in stackoverflow that this problem shows up when you try to put the bundle in a file different than src, but that's not the case, as I told you I leave everything by default; I mean I just enter the bundle name and then keep pressing enter until the proccess ends.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? what's the cause?
Thanks

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44948820/4224384, the default behavior has been changed.

Comment: So, you're saying that now it'll always give that error when creating a new bundle?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Edit composer.json:

Before:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
}'
```

After:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "NameofBundle\\": "src/NameofBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

Then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 24):

Only change composer.json:

Before:

```
"psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
```

After:

```
"psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
```

And finally, run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in symfony 3.4.4 too.I use this role in **composer.json**
And then the problem was fixed

befor

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

after

```
"autoload": {
     "classmap": [
       "app/AppKernel.php",
       "app/AppCache.php"
     ],
 "psr-4": {
 "": "src/"
 }
 },
```

> and then, cmd $ composer dump-autoload.