# unable to find template, after generating bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

ok this might be a very strange thing.
it's not the first time I work a symfony project but:

I used the symfony generate:bundle command and after that I created a bundle. Lets call it "CrimeBundle".

I saw it made a folder inside the src/

It also made automatically a DefaultController and an index.html.twig file.

Now whenever I use:

```
return $this->render('CrimeBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
```

it doesn't work: I get the error:

> Unable to find template "CrimeBundle:Default:index.html.twig" (looked into: /Users/admin/sites/solve/app/Resources/views, /Users/admin/sites/solve/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

however it works whenever I use the namespaced twig path like:

```
return $this->render('@Crime/Default/index.html.twig');
```

I like the first option, because on my other projects I use it too. None of them are the same version, currently I use: 3.4.1
Again the file is there, because it works with namespaced twig paths.

I can't understand why `return $this->render('CrimeBundle:Default:index.html.twig');` wouldn't work as symfony generated this code.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug.. It works with version 3.3.14 and it does not work with version 3.4.1. With both versions have another issue which you can read on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242838/symfony-3-bundle-creation-always-throws-edit-the-composer-json-file

Answer (score 5):

According to this - https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle
That's the only reference type the support for bundle templates

```
@BundleName/directory/filename.html.twig
```

If you go to docs for symfony 3.1 you'll see that was the last version that supported old reference

```
AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig
```

Comment: I totally understand but, what I don't understand is why is it automatically being created by symfony. I mean if it doesn't work like that, why is the generate:bundle command using the wrong reference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a pull request for this file
[SensioGeneratorBundle/bundle/DefaultController.php.twig](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Resources/skeleton/bundle/DefaultController.php.twig)

Comment: The link might answer the question but please provide a description her. Else once the link changes your answer turns useless.