# Error creation Bundle Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

I need your help, how can I fix this problem ?

When I create a new project symfony and I want to create my first bundle I get this message.

[image: Error creation new bundle]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony3 ClassNotFoundException after bundle creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation)

Answer (score 0):

try to add or edit into your composer.json the autoload configuration like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

After make a `composer dump-autoload` from your console

Comment: I did it, but i get the same problem. i don't know what is the problem

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to launch from your console composer dump-autoload @MounirZairig

Comment: I don't know about your system but at the start of the project you have launched something like composer install?  I don't know if you need to launch it with something like composer.phar or other things, It depends on your system

Comment: when i start the project I lunched the basic commande php symfony.phar new symfonyproject, but all composer commande don't work now i don't know how can I fix that

Comment: you need to launch composer into your project so try to make It works, but this is another question I think :)