# Doctrine - Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm, orm, entity

My terminal says that a certain class doesn't exist when updating schema through the command "php doctrine orm:schema-tool:update".

This is the response:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Emily\Controller\PageController' not found in /src/Emily/Controller/Page/Login.php on line 8
```

This is the source:

```
<?php

namespace Emily\Controller\Page;

use Emily\Controller\PageController;

class Login extends PageController
{

}
```

This is the parent/PageController:

```
<?php

namespace Emily\Controller;

use Emily\Controller\Controller;

class PageController extends Controller
{

}
```

I've checked names, paths, but all is in place. Why does doctrine keep telling me the class doesn't exist?

Many thanks!

Comment: Debug it using http://php.net/manual/ru/function.class-exists.php. It seems that either you didn't include it, or somewhere class path should start from root, otherwise it will be parsed as relative to current namespace

Comment: Verify your composer.json autoload section is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820  I did not see a Symfony tag on your question but it sure seems like the same sort of problem.  You need to ensure that composer knows about the Emily namespace.

Comment: @Cerad that seems to be the problem, thanks very much!

Comment: @Cerad I've added two paths, but it doesn't seem to recognize the "Controller" path:
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Emily\\Controller\\": "controller/",
            "Emily\\Core\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}

Comment: All you should really need is: "Emily\\": "src/" assuming your Emily code is under src.  Don't forget to run: composer dump-autoload after making changes to composer.json.

Comment: @Cerad composer dump-autoload made my day. Thanks!