# Symfony Generate new Bundle Failed to auto update autoload

Tags: symfony, bundle, autoload

I use Symfony Version 2.8. I get the following error when generating a new bundle.

[image: error screen shot]

I generate a new bundle using this command:

```
php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=FrontBundle --no-interaction
```

Then the console show me this results

> Bundle generation
>
> Generating a sample bundle skeleton into C:\xampp\htdocs\TRC\app/../src/FrontBundle
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/FrontBundle.php
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/Controller/
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
>         created .\app/../tests/FrontBundle/Controller/
>         created .\app/../tests/FrontBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/Resources/views/Default/
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/Resources/config/
>         created .\app/../src/FrontBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
>   Checking that the bundle is autoloaded
>       FAILED
>   Enabling the bundle inside C:\xampp\htdocs\TRC\app\AppKernel.php
>         updated .\app\AppKernel.php
>       OK
>   Importing the bundle's routes from the C:\xampp\htdocs\TRC\app\config\routing.yml file
>         updated .\app/config/routing.yml
>       OK
>   Importing the bundle's services.yml from the C:\xampp\htdocs\TRC\app\config\config.yml file
>         updated .\app/config/config.yml
>       OK
>
> The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
>   You'll need to make the following changes manually.
>
> Edit the composer.json file and register the bundle
>         namespace in the "autoload" section:
>
> Process finished with exit code 0 at 17:19:48.
>   Execution time: 719 ms.

Then I add a line to Composer.Json in autoload section:

```
#...
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
            "FrontBundle\\": "src/FrontBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
#.........
```

Finally, I use again the console to dump-autoload and when I refresh the page I get the same error.

I have tried to clear cache and force browser to refresh.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820  And update your question with the actual error message.  Nobody likes clicking on random links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
            "FrontBundle\\": "src/FrontBundle"
        },
```

Or better:

```
"psr-4": {
    "": "src/"
}
```

Comment: i replace `"psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
            "FrontBundle\\": "src/FrontBundle"
        },` by only `"psr-4": {
    "": "src/"
}`  ???

Comment: @AlaaEddineChebil yes, then anything in your src will be autoloaded.

Comment: i do that but the problem still not sloved

Comment: Be sure to run "composer dumpautoload" after updating composer.json

Comment: yes always i use `php composer.json dump-autoload` after updating composer.json but whene i just run 'php composer dump-autoload' like is it said in official symfony website he told me 'Could not open input file: composer'

Comment: Do you have composer installed globally?