# Symfony3 error adding new bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony3.x

I've a bundle that I created and is working in another project. I copied the Bundle folder inside the src folder, copied some segurity parameters, imported the service resource inside config.yml and add the bundle inside AppKernel.php as

> new LoginBundle\LoginBundle()

And when I made a `$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` it return this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "LoginBundle" from namespace "LoginBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in {project}\app\AppKernel.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 {project}\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php(450): AppKernel->registerBundles()
#1 {project}\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php(116): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
#2 {project}\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php(69): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 {project}\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(125): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {project}\bin\console(27): Symfo in {project}\app\AppKernel.php on line 18
```

---

EDIT

AppKernel.php content

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new LoginBundle\LoginBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

            if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
            }
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

And here goes the bundle file structure

[image: bundle structure]

Also this is the LoginBundle.php

```
namespace LoginBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class LoginBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Comment: Please, show us the content of the AppKernel.php.
Also, how the structure of the bundle looks?

Comment: There it go @MatkoĐipalo

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820 Here is a hint.  Just paste a portion of the actual error message into a browser search bar.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad I got another problem now: Unrecognized option "login_path" under "security.firewalls.form_login"

Comment: @BraianMellor And of course you searched for the error message and came up empty?

Comment: I needed to add secured_area inside firewalls, good work symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was generating aoutoloaders again like

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score -1):

i think in routing.yml you must add

```
login:
    resource: "@LoginBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: Nice try but can you think of how a routing issue might lead to a class not found exception?