# Symfony ErrorHandler scanning whole hard drive

Tags: symfony, exception

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and I recently made local changes like moving a Bundle from `src/subfolder/MyBundle` to `src/MyBundle`.

**My problem**: When having a `ClassNotFoundException`, the behavior of Symfony changed, the exception is triggering Symfony to discover my whole hard drive instead of my project only.

**Situation**: for the example I simply deleted a `use` statement from one of my move Bundle's sources :

```
//use CallMapBundle\Authentification;
```

**Before the changes (expected behavior)**:

```
Attempted to load class "Authentication" from namespace "FE\CallMapBundle\Bundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

**After the changes**:

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(//var/lib/apt/lists/partial): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('//var/lib/apt/l...', 4096)
#1 /path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php(148): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->getChildren()
#2 /path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php(117): Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->findClassInPath('/', 'DemandeCours', 'myfunctions')
#3 /path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php(63): Sym
at n/a
    in /path/to/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php line 148
```

My question is why is now Symfony trying to scan my whole hard drive ?

Comment: You need to update the psr4 section of composer.json and run composer dumpautoload.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you explain how I should modify the psr-4 section ? Or link some documentation ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation

Comment: I updated the psr-4 section with my different bundles but it still throws me a permission error. I got back to `"": "src/"` wich is proper with S 2.7

Comment: I can't tell from your posted code what is and is not correct.  Your conclusion that Symfony is somehow scanning the entire drive is dubious at best.  Might want to take a look at the generated composer autoload files to see how psr4 works.