# How to generate bundle without bugs problems on AppKernel.php page?

Tags: symfony, debugging, bundle

When I generate a new bundle I receive the error notice that kind:

"Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "myBundle" from namespace "my\myBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in C:\wamp64\www\symfony\app\AppKernel.php"

Comment: How does your composer.json looks like? Is there a section `"autoload" :  "psr-4": { "": "src/"} ` ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820  Hint: first step in getting help is to paste the error message into a search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in autoload section of composer.json replace the entry

```
"psr-4": { "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle" },
```

for

```
"psr-4": { "": "src/" },
```

then execute composer dumpautoload.

that worked for me.