# Symfony 4: Reusable code in "src"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to update a Symfony 3.4 application to Symfony 4. On my current applications I always share a local `AdminBundle` folder inside `src`. I know Symfony 4 recommends to be "bundle-less" now. But this AdminBundle is the base for most of my projects, and sometimes I make some updates to it that can be deployed to all my projects just pushing to the repository.

I tried to move by AdminBundle inside `src` but obviously that's not working. Could anyone detail the recipe or configuration needed to make this Bundle work under Symfony 4 in a generic way?

If this is not possible what's the best way to create a reusable code in symfony 4?

Comment: Why not move the AdminBundle into it's own project so you can require it using Composer as (other) 3rd party bundles?

Comment: I don't want to make this bundle public. Can I do this with a private repository? I guess it's still possible to create Bundles on Symfony 4?

Comment: Yes you can use private repositories https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories

Comment: Thanks @JimL, I think it's now the exact solution to my question, but probably a smarter and better way of doing the same thing.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Class not found exceptions?  Should be no problem at all in having a src/AdminBundle in S4 even if it is not the best solution.  But a few details might help.

Comment: It tries to find namespaces prefixed with "App/".

Comment: Probably just need to adjust the psr4 section of composer.json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820

Comment: This approach - though it's framework agnostic - might help you: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/12/25/composer-local-packages-for-dummies

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a similiar approach:
I've got a "CoreBundle" for shared Services, Entites, Subscribers etc under "src".

In order to make this usable i had to edit the following:

config/maker.yaml -> to use make:entity and create under CoreBundle

```
maker:
  root_namespace: 'App\CoreBundle'
```

config/packages/doctrine.yaml modify -> to get the Entities from CoreBundle

```
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
      App:
        is_bundle: false
        type: annotation
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/CoreBundle/Entity'
        prefix: 'App\CoreBundle\Entity'
        alias: App
```

config/services.yaml add -> to import all SymfonyLike Classes

```
  ###> CoreBundle ###
  App\CoreBundle\:
    resource: '../src/CoreBundle/*'
    exclude: '../src/CoreBundle/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Model,Migrations,Tests}'

  App\CoreBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/CoreBundle/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
  ###< CoreBundle ###
```

config/* add -> where i wanted to import a separate config file

```
imports:
  - { resource: '../../src/CoreBundle/Resources/config/*.yaml' }
```