# error while extending the bundle ClassNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, bundle, sonata-admin

I just created a new 2.8 `Symfony` project then added SonataAdminBundle
when I tried to add SonataMediaundle as you can see in the screenshot after completing step 2.5 in the documentation I get this error that I just couldn't explain.

[image: image description here]

[image: image description here]

(I'm a new user so I can't add pictures yet so you'll only see the link)

Comment: Have you try `composer install`?

Comment: You have to install the bundle first using composer.  `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle`. Please don't post images it's heavy to read. Just post the relevant part of your code

Comment: yes i tried `composer install` and both sonata admin and sonata media are installed

Comment: Typically these sort of class not found exceptions indicate you need to update the psr4 section of composer.json.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820 and https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/902

Comment: thanks Cerad. problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, Cerad, the problem solved thanks to you,
by changing the autoload in my composer.json file from this:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
```

To this:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
```

then run command:

> composer dumpautoload

and Voilà everything come back to work.