# Symfony : The autoloader expected class to be defined in class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I searched for a long time on the web but I do not understand my error.
Could you help me ?

I'm on Symfony 3.4

**The error :**

```
(1/1) RuntimeException
The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Controller\MessagingController" to be defined in file "/home/thomas/Documents/Projects/ludiproject_api/vendor/composer/../../src/AppBundle/Controller/MessagingController.php". 
The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

**Here my entity :**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppBundle\Entity\Messaging
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="messaging")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MessagingRepository")
 */
class Messaging
{
```

**Here my Controller :**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Messaging;
use DateTime;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

class MessagingController extends Controller
{
```

**Here my repository :**

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MessagingRepository extends EntityRepository
{
```

Comment: Can you copy / pase `autoload` > `psr-4` from your composer.json ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820

Answer (score 0):

**I found it !**

Need to add "repository-class="AppBundle\Repository\MessagingRepository" in Messaging.orm.xml.

```
<entity name="AppBundle\Entity\Messaging" table="messaging" repository-class="AppBundle\Repository\MessagingRepository">
```