# Symfony2.8 -> 3,3 Attempted to load class "AcmeTopBundle" from namespace "Acme\TopBundle"

Tags: php, symfony

I am upgrading symfony 2.8 -> 3.3

I have bumped into the issue.

in AppKernel.app

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
     new Acme\TopBundle\AcmeTopBundle(),
     new Acme\UserBundle\UserBundle(),
     new Acme\AdminBundle\AcmeAdminBundle(),
```

Normally I register my original bundles like this.

However in 3.3 it shows the error,

`Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "AcmeTopBundle" from namespace "Acme\TopBundle".`

All part of AppKernel.php except `registerBundles()`, I copy and paste from new 3.3 skeleton project.
Also `AppCache.php` is also copied.

How can I register my original bundle into 3.3????

---

The problem is solved , thanks to the comments.

my solution is like this below in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",

        "Acme\\TopBundle\\": "src/Acme/TopBundle", //add
        "Acme\\UserBundle\\": "src/Acme/UserBundle", //add
        "Acme\\MemberBundle\\": "src/Acme/MemberBundle", //add
        "Acme\\AdminBundle\\": "src/Acme/AdminBundle" //add
    },
```

Comment: in my project when I want register my own bundle I do this:
new AcmeTopBundle\AcmeTopBundle() 
and this works well

Comment: Just to be sure, the File AcmeTopBundle.php is present in your bundle, the class name is AcmeTopBundle and the namespace is Acme\TopBundle and you cleared the cache?

Comment: Some of the psr-4 stuff in composer.json was tweaked in Symfony 3.x.  See if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820).

Comment: Yes, in src/AcmeTopBundle I have AcmeTopBundle.php but the namespace of this is AcmeTopBundle, because the namespace starts from src.

Comment: also I put in composer.json autoload psr-4, as Cerad says

Comment: I have solved my problem. thanks to your comments. I updated the article.