# Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Use rBundle" from namespace "UserBundle\UserBundle"

Tags: php, symfony

```
php bin/console clear-cache:
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Use
>   rBundle" from namespace "UserBundle\UserBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /var/www/html/projects/Event-Finance/api/app/AppKernel.php:21
>   Stack trace:#0 /var/www/html/projects/Event-Finance/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(48
>   8): AppKernel->registerBundles()#1 /var/www/html/projects/Event-Finance/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(13
>   2): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
>   #2 /var/www/html/projects/Event-Finance/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/App
>   lication.php(64): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
>   #3 /var/www/html/projects/Event-Finance/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(
>   148): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Componen in /var/www/html/projects/Event-Finance/api/app/AppKernel.php on line 21

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820

Answer (score 1):

I have passed 2 days to fix this error by uploading, configuring symfony several time. Changing the directory permissions and so many thing. Finally I have fix this issues in my Symfony 3.4 project.

There are 2 things you need to do to fix this error:

1. In the composer.json, modify the psr-4 section under autoload section like this.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
},
```

2. Then execute the following command

`composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Thanks. This helped me fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your bundle name:

**Use rBundle** should be UserBundle.