# Symfony 3.3 The autoloader expected class

Tags: php, forms, symfony, authentication

I've got a problem with my Symfony project. I'm trying to put a form login authenticator and for that I need to create a repository of my user class. However, i've got that error :

The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository" to be defined in file "C:\wamp64\www\Symfony\vendor\composer/../../src\AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Here's my UserRepository class :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\EntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;


class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT u FROM AppBundle:User u ORDER BY u.username ASC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}

?>
```

My User entity :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $apiKey;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getApiKey()
    {
        return $this->apiKey;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
    }
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function setUsername($_username)
    {
        $this->username = $_username;
    }

    public function setPassword($_password)
    {
        $this->password = $_password;
    }


    public function setId($_id)
    {
        return $this->id = $_id;
    }

    public function setApiKey($_apiKey)
    {
        return $this->apiKey = $_apiKey;
    }
}
?>
```

My security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - AppBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

And finally my FormLoginAuthenticator :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
            return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'app_login'
            && $request->isMethod('POST');

    }
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
               return [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
        ];
    }
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        return $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);
    }
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
          die($user);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        // todo
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getLoginUrl() method.
    }

}
?>
```

Thanks you by advance for helping me. Also, if you have a better solution to build my form authenticator, it will be very nice.

Comment: Looks like you've correctly included the good namespace / class name in the file. Give a try to `php bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: By the way, **do not** close php tag `?>` in files that has only php code, to avoid sending white spaces before doctype declaration

Comment: [You need to tweak the psr-4 section of composer.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946911/symfony3-classnotfoundexception-after-bundle-creation/44948820#44948820).

Comment: Thanks you for the anwsers but nothing is working..