# Symfony bundle error

Tags: symfony

How can i solve this error.

I created one bundle with console. But I get this error of following code. Where do i mistake?

```
$bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle\AcmeBundleBlogBundle(),
    );


Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "AcmeBundleBlogBundle" from namespace "Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in C:\nexampp\htdocs\my_project\app\AppKernel.php:20
Stack trace:
#0         C:\nexampp\htdocs\my_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php(433): AppKernel->registerBundles()
```

Comment: Can you please add your AcmeBundleBlogBundle.php file code located at your bundle folder

Comment: Assuming you do indeed have a use statement for your blog bundle then take a look at the autoload section of composer.json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928982/appkernel-php-weird-behavior#comment76834486_44928982

Comment: Thank you for you return, you are super